# Ansible ask for password to ansible vault from other group vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-vault

I have problem with ansible. 
I have couple of group_vars folders and in this folders there is files encrypted by ansible-vault with difference passwords between prod and test:

```
├── group_vars
│   ├── app1_prod
│   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault prod pass
│   │   └── service.yml
│   ├── app1_test
│   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault test pass
│   │   └── service.yml
│   ├── app2_prod
│   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault prod pass
│   │   └── service.yml
│   └── app2_test
│       ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault test pass
│       └── service.yml
```

And my inventory file looks like:

```
[test_hosts]
test_host1
test_host2

[prod_hosts]
prod_host1
prod_host2

[app1_test:children]
test_hosts

[app2_test:children]
test_hosts

[app1_prod:children]
prod_hosts

[app2_prod:children]
prod_hosts
```

When I running playbook command:

```
ansible-playbook app1_playbook.yml -i ./inventory/hosts -l app1_test -u ssh_user -k --vault-password-file path_to_vault_key
```

I get error that saying the vault password is wrong for file and pointing for file in prod and from other group:

```
Decryption failed on ansible/group_vars/app1_prod/application.yml
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I assume you have different files for the different keys.  Try putting both files on the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I think your inventory structure is a Bad Idea.  I do not condone having PROD and TEST servers in the same inventory, and I see no good reason for it.

I would restructure your system like this:

```
├── prod
│   ├── ansible.cfg
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   ├── app1
│   │   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault prod pass
│   │   │   └── service.yml
│   │   ├── app2
│   │   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault prod pass
│   │   │   └── service.yml
├── test
│   ├── ansible.cfg
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   ├── app1
│   │   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault prod pass
│   │   │   └── service.yml
│   │   ├── app2
│   │   │   ├── application.yml <- Ancryptes by Ansible Vault prod pass
│   │   │   └── service.yml
```

And, of course, there would be two host files:

PROD:

```
[hosts]
prod_host1
prod_host2

[app1:children]
hosts

[app2:children]
hosts
```

TEST:

```
[hosts]
test_host1
test_host2

[app1:children]
hosts

[app2:children]
hosts
```

Have an `ansible.cfg` file in each inventory directory with the lines:

```
inventory      = .
vault_password_file = /path/to/vault_password_file
remote_user = ssh_user
ask_pass = True
```

(Best if you just copy `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` to the inventory directory and change what you need to change.)

Once you have that setup, you go into the `prod` or `test` directory, and execute the playbook from there.  Of course, you will need to specify the path to the playbooks:

```
cd prod
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbooks/app_playbook.yml

cd test
ansible-playbook /path/to/playbooks/app_playbook.yml
```

Trust me, life is much easier with inventory separation.

Good luck!

Comment: Thx for the tip. I'm implement this idea in my env. I'm simply still lacking of good practices.

Comment: After I split ma inventory there is problem that ansible don't see my group_vars. I start playbook from test folder like you says. Do you know how its possible?

Comment: The `group_vars` directory is under `test`?  Did you make sure the group names match the files in `group_vars`?